# Alternative command of document.body.innerHTML in prototype js

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Alternative command for document.body.innerHTML prototype.

I need to change innerhtml of document in prototype what's the alternative command of document.body.innerHTML in prototype js.

Comment: What have you found in google?

Comment: Please tell us what abut `document.body.innerHTML` does not work for you. There are no "alternative"s, that would just be redundant.

Comment: I suppose you could do `$$('body').first().update('your html here');`, but as noted earlier, this is just a wrapper around innerHTML=. The benefit of course to using update() is that the element will remain extended (in Prototype.js parlance), and any inserted elements will also be extended. Prototype will not stop working, in other words, in elderly browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have the dom element id then you may use:

```
 $('<idOfElement>').update('Text here');
```

further if you want to change the html as such including tags

```
 $('<idOfElement>').update('<h1>Text here</h1>');
```

or if you want to change the content of the body tag itself

```
 document.body.update('Text here');
```

further if you want to change the html as such including tags

```
 document.body.update('<h5>Text here</h5>');
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //<p> Hello, <b>World</b>!</p>
 var para = document.createElement('p');
  para.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hello, '));

 // <b>
 var b = document.createElement('b');
 b.appendChild(document.createTextNode('World');
para.appendChild(b);

para.appendChild(document.createTextNode('!'));

// Do something with the para element, add it to the document, etc.
```

also,

```
  var node = document.getElementById("one");

 while( node.firstChild )
    node.removeChild( node.firstChild );
    node.appendChild( document.createTextNode("Two") );
```